# Apply multiple ncover coverage filters

Tags: code-coverage, ncover

I am running a merge using ncover.reporting on a slew of assemblies (250+) and am trying to apply coverage filters to only include assemblies that start with my teams namespace prefix (Infrastructure*) and exclude coverage on getters and setters. I wrote a basic batch file that looks something like this:

```
NCover.Reporting
  C:\hudson\jobs\Infrastructure.Members.Api\workspace\Infrastructure.Members.Api.Test-dll-coverage-results.xml
  C:\hudson\jobs\Infrasctucture.REST.Proxy\workspace\Infrasctucture.REST.Proxy.Test-dll-coverage-results.xml
  ...
  //s MergeCoverage.xml
  //cf "Infrastructure*":Assembly:False:True
  //cf "*get_*":Method
  //cf "*set_*":Method
  //or FullCoverageReport:Html
  //op "C:\NCoverProjects\Reports\FullCoverageReport"
  //p "Infrastructure"
```

However, when I view FullCoverageReport.html I still see the dependent assemblies and getters and setters being included. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which version of NCover do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved on NCover Forum, re-posting answer here:

I tried these filters on one of my test projects: //cf "BusinessObjects*":Assembly:False:True
//cf "*get*":Method //cf "*set*":Method

Only BusinessObjects was included, and all my get and set methods were excluded. Hopefully, that modified wildcard syntax will work as you expect. I was also successful with regex pattern 'get.*'